# Django - queryset disappears after update command

Tags: django

I have a simple Django command like so:

```
class OrderQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def filter_vendor(self, vendor):
        return self.filter(agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__agreement_vendors__vendor = vendor)
    def suggestions(self, legal_entity_own):
        result = self.filter(status_id = 1, is_active_flg = 1)
        pending_orders = Order.objects.filter_legal_entity_own(legal_entity_own).\
                                       with_pending_status()
        vendor_id_list = pending_orders.values('agreement_vendors_merchandise_list__agreement_vendors__vendor').distinct()
        vendors = Vendors.objects.exclude(id__in = vendor_id_list) 
        result = result.filter_vendors(vendors) 
        return result

class Order(models.Model):
      objects = OrderQuerySet.as_manager()

def my_strange_behaviour_view
    suggested_orders_qs = Order.objects.suggestions(legal_entity_own_instance).\
                                            filter(chosen_quantity__gt = 0)    
    order_qs_by_vendor = suggested_orders_qs.filter_vendor(v)
    order_qs_by_vendor.update(status_id = 2) # This command makes the queryset empty
```

After this command, the querysets becomes empty !
I am just lost. And can't find any hint in documentation. Can anyone explain what's going on ?

Comment: Suggestion - if you are trying to build a multistep filter, instead of applying multiple filters to a queryset, you can instead build a list of filters and apply it once at the end (same with aggregates, extra values, exclusions, ordering).

Comment: Serg, could you please provide a short example of what you mean by "list of filters"

Comment: I mean that instead of chaining filters like this `queryset.filter(field1='value1').filter(field2='value2')`, it might be more convenient to build a dictionary of filters first `filters={'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}` and then apply them once `queryset.filter(**filters)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `suggestions` queryset method already filtered using `status_id=1` so when you updated the queryset with `status_id=2` the queryset simply does not hold further data because of filtering applied via `status_id=1`

In order to preserve you need a shallow copy of original queryset before update:

```
import copy
original_qs = copy.copy(order_qs_by_vendor)
order_qs_by_vendor.update(status_id=2)
# now try to do original_qs.count() but it will still hold the status_id=1 though
```

Comment: Well, I see this. The question is, doesn't Django give tools to update queryset so that you don't loose the collection of elements ?